# When does true altitude equal indicated altitude?

Tags: flight-instruments

Under what conditions is true altitude is equal to indicated altitude? When the sea level pressure is 29.92 in Hg and the temperature is standard for a given altitude, for example 9 degrees at 3000 ft? Under what other condition(s) they are both equal? Or is that the only one?

Answer (score 4):

The first part is one of the many poorly-worded test prep questions in the pilot training world. Yes, standard pressure and standard temperature are the only two conditions they are looking for.

Pressure and temperature are the only significant variables. Humidity has some measurable effect on density but it is relatively small and difficult to predict so ignored in practical flight. Specifically, the lapse rates are important, but the lapse rates can only be approximated for practical aviation purposes.

It is possible for real-world temperature and pressure to diverge away from standard atmosphere such that they will have counteracting effects and result in a true altitude that matches indicated altitude at one specific point, but that is not generally useful to a pilot in flight. However, it is really similar to the source of the altimeter setting for an airport. The pressure setting is(for higher elevation airports) often not the setting that would be found at true sea level, it is the setting that yields an equal indicated altitude and true altitude at the airport elevation(but usually no other altitude). Again this is due to non-standard lapse rates.

Comment: Your answer brings up a point which seems to be less well known for some reason, which is that accurate altitude in relation to the ground is more important when you are somewhat near the ground, but at higher altitudes what is more important is accurate altitude in relation to other aircraft. Which is why above 18,000 feet everyone sets their altimeter to 29.92. So if one plane has an indicated altitude of say 29,000 feet and another aircraft has an indicated altitude of 30,000 feet they can be relatively sure that they have 1,000 ft vertical separation. Not that the OP is unaware of this.